# coordinate-free proof of transitivity of norms or traces

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello:

Suppose $A$ is a finite free $B$-algebra and $B$ is a finite free $C$-algebra. Does anyone
know a coordinate-free proof (i.e. without choosing bases) of the identity:

$N_{A/C} = N_{B/C}\circ N_{A/B}$?

Where $N_{A/C}(a)$ is the determinant of mulitiplication by an element $a\in A$, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: You must also assume $B$ and $C$ are of finite rank.  Further, this follows from basic facts about the determinant.

Comment: If $M$ finite free of $B$-rk $s$ and $B$ finite free of $C$-rk $r$, there's functorial $C$-linear isom  $f:\det_C(B)^{\otimes s} \otimes {\rm{N}}_{B/C}(\det_B(M)) \simeq \det_C(M)$ (use "norm" of line bundles), so for $B$-linear end. $T$ of $M$ comparing multipliers in $C$ gives ${\rm{N}}_{B/C}(\det_B(T)) = \det_C(T)$ (try $M = A$ and $T$ is mult. by $a \in A$). Define $f$ by $(b_1 \wedge \dots \wedge b_r)^{\otimes s} \otimes {\rm{N}}_{B/C}(m_1 \wedge \dots \wedge m_s) \mapsto b_1 m_1 \wedge \dots \wedge b_r m_s$. To prove well-def'd isom...use bases (cf. 4.2, Ch.II of Oesterle, Inv. Math. 78)

Comment: Dear Harry: kkk is assuming finite rank; reread the question. I do not agree that this follows from basic facts about the determinant. It is a subtle fact about algebra structures.  Even for finite extensions of fields there is not a "trivial" proof. Write out a proof for yourself using just "basic facts" about the det, and I am sure you will find an error.

Comment: Harry, I think you mean $A$ and $B$, and I think the questioner did assume that. What is the basic fact that you have in mind? And further, do you know a coordinate-free proof of it? 

Comment: I changed your name to k3.  Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Concerning BCnrd's reference to the field case being tricky, I'm reminded of a take-home midterm exam from my Galois theory class in college. One problem was to prove transitivity of the trace and norm for finite extensions of fields. The trace case was quite simple but the norm case was amazingly hard by comparison (we did not know about inseparable degrees). 

Comment: Already 3 people are voting to close: not fair.  I think this is a really good question. 

Comment: I agree with KConrad, and I will resort to the unofficial-but-somewhat-endorsed by meta practice of **casting a vote for the question to remain open**.

Comment: @BCnrd: What do you mean by $\det_C(B)$?